# Browser hangs while using ng-pattern in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, browser, ng-pattern

Input field using ng-pattern as

```
<input name="name" ng-model="name" type="text" maxlength="50"  ng-required="true" ng-pattern="/^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+){5,50}$/" />
```

Its working fine, when model value has minimum number of characters.
While model value has more than 40 characters, trying to add some characters as @ the browser hangs (Firefox/chrome).

Somtimes it showing error in firebug as

```
Error: too much recursion
link/c.$validators.pattern@http://localhost/testApp/js/app/angular.min.js:314:9
d/<@http://localhost/testApp/js/app/angular.min.js:284:352
q@http://localhost/testApp/js/app/angular.min.js:8:3
d@http://localhost/testApp/js/app/angular.min.js:284:316
Pg</this.$$runValidators@http://localhost/testApp/js/app/angular.min.js:285:443
Pg</this.$$parseAndValidate@http://localhost/testApp/js/app/angular.min.js:287:69
Pg</this.$commitViewValue@http://localhost/testApp/js/app/angular.min.js:286:183
Pg</this.$$debounceViewValueCommit/<@http://localhost/testApp/js/app/angular.min.js:288:199
$eval@http://localhost/testApp/js/app/angular.min.js:145:347
$apply@http://localhost/testApp/js/app/angular.min.js:146:52
Pg</this.$$debounceViewValueCommit@http://localhost/testApp/js/app/angular.min.js:288:179
Pg</this.$setViewValue@http://localhost/testApp/js/app/angular.min.js:287:411
l@http://localhost/testApp/js/app/angular.min.js:177:283
dispatch@http://localhost/testApp/js/jquery.min.1.11.3.js:4:8549
add/r.handle@http://localhost/testApp/js/jquery.min.1.11.3.js:4:5252
2 angular.min.js:118:10
```

Comment: Your regex pattern only allow alphanumeric values plus underscore, and dash.

Comment: yes these are the allowed values, whiles user  trying with @ it should show validation message. but i am getting  error as too much recursion